# Android 11 Парсинг динамических web страниц в фоне

Tags: android, парсер, android-service

Подскажите библиотеку для Android 11, которая позволяет в фоне (сервисе) парсить динамически созданные web странички?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В приложении есть сервис. Нужно что бы этот сервис спарсил страницу с сайта. Страница генерируется js динамически